# How to start reading some part of the text in a file once a keyword preceeding the text is found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, character, getline, words

Here's a code i wrote...pretty basic as I'm a beginner.....

The source file looks like:

```
Integers:
1 2 3 4 56 ...

String:
This is a string......
...(text).....
```

The code should read the text depending on the keywords it encounters at the beginning,,,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int i;
    string STRING;
    char *inname = "source.txt";
    ifstream infile(inname);

    if (!infile) 
    {
        cout << "There was a problem opening file "<< inname<< " for reading."<< endl;
        return 0;
    };
    while (STRING != "Integer:")
        {
            getline(infile,STRING); // Saves the line in STRING.

            cout<<STRING<<endl; // Prints our STRING.
        };

    };
    cout << "Opened " << inname << " for reading." << endl<<endl<<"Integers:";
    while (infile >> i) {
        cout<<endl<<i<<endl;
    infile.close();
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For starters, I think looking for the line that *starts* with "Integers:" rather then *equals* "Integer:" may have tremendous benefit. Learning about string streams will probably bode well for you also. Of course, you could also have the question formatted so it *looks* like `Integers:` and the numbers that follow are on the same line, when in fact they are not; likewise for `String:`.

Comment: thnx...btw source file has 'Integer:'in it....

Comment: Yeah,, its different in your code and in the question; likely what threw me off. sorry about that.

Comment: Yeah....btw can string compare be used for the purpose?

Comment: Honestly, your input is super simple. I'd probably read it line by line, check the lead token for your "Integer:", "String:", skip it if it is either, and depending on which it was, feed the rest of the line to a stringstream that busts it into either `int`s or `std::string`s. if the next line starts with neither, then just keep reading what you were before, only switching when a new line starts with a different token. Something like that. you know your problem-space better than we do, so go with whatever truly works for you.

Comment: Is it *just* one "Integer:" and one "String:" section, or is it possible to have multiple similar sections, and also, by your sample, is it guaranteed a *blank* line will separate sections? These are all things that you should be considering when approaching this problem if you're breaking it apart like this

Comment: Thanks man....hope dat helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to tokenize the words found in the line. There are many ways of doing this, you can use [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/), [boost tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/tokenizer/), or even write your own code.

Assuming you create a rule where each word (token) is separated by spaces, and you've managed to tokenize the lines, then you can just write a code checking the first token in the line and action appropriately

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you are missing some state in your parser, some check if the file is still valid and parsing the integers.

Here is a proof of concept:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace {

  void parse_integers(std::vector<int> & vi, std::string const & line) {
    // Using strtol here - other tokenizers are possible.
    char const * ip { line.c_str() };
    char * ep;

    do {
      long int const v { strtol( ip, &ep, 10 ) };
      vi.push_back( v );
      ip = ep;
    } while( *ep != '\0' );

  }
}

int main() {

  std::string   inname { "source.txt" };
  std::ifstream infile { inname };

  if( ! infile ) {
    std::cout << "There was a problem opening file "
          << inname << " for reading." << std::endl;
        return 0;
  };

  enum class ParseState {
    outer, found_integers, found_string
  };

  ParseState ps { ParseState::outer };

  std::vector<int> s_integers;
  std::string      s_string;

  while( infile ) {
    std::string line;
    getline( infile, line );

    // Skip empty lines
    if( line.size() == 0 ) {
      continue;
    }

    if( line == "Integers:" ) {
      ps = ParseState::found_integers;
      continue;
    } else if( line == "String:" ) {
      ps = ParseState::found_string;
      continue;
    }

    // Hope that a section was already found....
    if( ps == ParseState::outer ) {
      std::cerr << "Line with data but without a section found ["
        << line << "]" << std::endl;
      continue;
    }

    switch( ps ) {
    case ParseState::found_integers:
      parse_integers(s_integers, line);
      break;

    case ParseState::found_string:
      s_string += line + "\n";
      break;

    case ParseState::outer:
      // Cannot happen
      abort();
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Dump file contents" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Strings: [" << s_string << "]" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Integers: ";
  for(int i : s_integers) {
    std::cout << "[" << i << "] ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
Integers:
1 2 3 4 56 111 761 777

String:
This is a string......
...(text).....
```

Output:

```
Dump file contents
Strings: [This is a string......
...(text).....
]
Integers: [1] [2] [3] [4] [56] [111] [761] [777]
```